# SKlearn: Gaussian Process Regression not changed during learning

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, gaussian

I'm trying to fit a GP using a `GaussianProcessRegressor`, and I notice that my hyperparameters are still at their initial values. I did some stepping in gpr.py, but wasn't able to pinpoint the exact reason for this. Prediction with the initial values yields a zero line.

My data consists 5400 samples, each having 12 features, mapped to a single output variable. Even though the design might not be that well, I still would expect some learning.

Required files:

[features.txt](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hl1r4ex5ebw0eoa/features.txt?dl=0)

[output.txt](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9np2v4n77sa35cx/output.txt?dl=0)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import RBF, ConstantKernel,WhiteKernel

designmatrix = pd.read_csv('features.txt', index_col = 0)
y = pd.read_csv('output.txt', header=None, index_col = 0)

# The RBF kernel is a stationary kernel. It is also known as the “squared exponential” kernel. 
# It is parameterized by a length-scale parameter length_scale>0, which can either be a scalar (isotropic variant of the kernel) 
# or a vector with the same number of dimensions as the inputs X (anisotropic variant of the kernel). 
# 
# The ConstantKernel can be used as part of a product-kernel where it scales the magnitude of the other factor (kernel) or as 
# part of a sum-kernel, where it modifies the mean of the Gaussian process.
#
# The main use-case of the White kernel is as part of a sum-kernel where it explains the noise-component of the signal. 
# Tuning its parameter corresponds to estimating the noise-level: k(x_1, x_2) = noise_level if x_1 == x_2 else 0

kernel = ConstantKernel(0.1, (1e-23, 1e5)) * 
RBF(0.1*np.ones(designmatrix.shape[1]), (1e-23, 1e10) ) + WhiteKernel(0.1, (1e-23, 1e5))

gp = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel, n_restarts_optimizer=0)

print('Training')
t = time.time()
gp = gp.fit(designmatrix, y)
elapsed = time.time() - t
print(elapsed)

score = gp.score(designmatrix, y)
print(score)

print("initial params")
params = gp.get_params()
print(params)
print("learned kernel params")
print(gp.kernel_.get_params())
```

The result is the following:

```
initial params

{'alpha': 1e-10, 'copy_X_train': True, 'kernel__k1': 1**2, 'kernel__k2': RBF(len
gth_scale=[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]), 'kernel__k1__constant_value': 1
.0, 'kernel__k1__constant_value_bounds': (1e-05, 100000.0), 'kernel__k2__length_
scale': array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]), 'ke
rnel__k2__length_scale_bounds': (1e-05, 100000.0), 'kernel': 1**2 * RBF(length_s
cale=[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]), 'n_restarts_optimizer': 0, 'normaliz
e_y': False, 'optimizer': 'fmin_l_bfgs_b', 'random_state': None}

learned kernel params

{'k1': 1**2, 'k2': RBF(length_scale=[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]), 'k1__
constant_value': 1.0, 'k1__constant_value_bounds': (1e-05, 100000.0), 'k2__lengt
h_scale': array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]), '
k2__length_scale_bounds': (1e-05, 100000.0)}
```

So, the kernel parameters are unchanged...

- Is there a way to check for warnings?
- Am I doing something wrong, or is there something I could check?

Any help would be really appreciated...

Ben

Comment: That does seem odd, can you check you get weird results with: `print("initial params\n")
print(gp.kernel.get_params())
gp.fit(X, y)
print("\nlearned kernel params")
print(gp.kernel_.get_params())` Sorry for the hideous formatting, but I don't have an answer yet!

Comment: `get_params()` returns only the hyper-parameters of the classification, not the learned attributes. Hyper-parameters are not changed. See [the documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.gaussian_process.GaussianProcessRegressor.html) under `attributes` section to know what will be changed.

Comment: @Vivek Kumar The ``kernel_`` (mind the underscore) attribute does contain the optimized hyperparameters for the standard examples

Comment: But then again you are calling get_params() on kernel, which again will only return the parameters used at initialize time. The optimized params for kernel object are `theta` and `bounds`. See [this for example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/gaussian_process.html#gaussian-process-kernel-api)

Comment: @Vivek Kumar I'm calling ``gp.kernel_.get_params()`` :)

Answer (score 7):

**NOT AN ANSWER (YET)**

**Begin Note**

The data is too big for an SO question, and it takes too long for us to test your issue. I've changed your code to include only the first 600 lines from each file. Your code the way pasted here also doesn't run, I've fixed that.

**End Note**

Using `python 3.6.4`, `scikit-learn==0.19.1`, and `numpy==1.14.2`.

As you see in the documentation of `n_restarts_optimizer`, you need to have it larger than 0 if you want to optimize the kernel hyperparameters.\

> ```
> n_restarts_optimizer : int, optional (default: 0)
>     The number of restarts of the optimizer for finding the kernel's
>     parameters which maximize the log-marginal likelihood. The first run
>     of the optimizer is performed from the kernel's initial parameters,
>     the remaining ones (if any) from thetas sampled log-uniform randomly
>     from the space of allowed theta-values. If greater than 0, all bounds
>     must be finite. Note that n_restarts_optimizer == 0 implies that one
>     run is performed.
> ```

So changing the value to `2` from `0` in your code, results in the following output:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import RBF, ConstantKernel,WhiteKernel

designmatrix = pd.read_csv('features.txt', index_col = 0).iloc[0:600,]
y = pd.read_csv('output.txt', header=None, index_col = 0).iloc[0:600,]

# The RBF kernel is a stationary kernel. It is also known as the “squared exponential” kernel. 
# It is parameterized by a length-scale parameter length_scale>0, which can either be a scalar (isotropic variant of the kernel) 
# or a vector with the same number of dimensions as the inputs X (anisotropic variant of the kernel). 
# 
# The ConstantKernel can be used as part of a product-kernel where it scales the magnitude of the other factor (kernel) or as 
# part of a sum-kernel, where it modifies the mean of the Gaussian process.
#
# The main use-case of the White kernel is as part of a sum-kernel where it explains the noise-component of the signal. 
# Tuning its parameter corresponds to estimating the noise-level: k(x_1, x_2) = noise_level if x_1 == x_2 else 0

kernel = ConstantKernel(0.1, (1e-23, 1e5)) * \
         RBF(0.1*np.ones(designmatrix.shape[1]), (1e-23, 1e10) ) + \
         WhiteKernel(0.1, (1e-23, 1e5))

gp = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel, n_restarts_optimizer=2)

print("initial params")
params = gp.get_params()
print(params)

print('Training')
t = time.time()
gp = gp.fit(designmatrix, y)
elapsed = time.time() - t
print(elapsed)

score = gp.score(designmatrix, y)
print(score)

print("learned kernel params")
print(gp.kernel_.get_params())
```

And the output:

```
initial params
{'alpha': 1e-10, 'copy_X_train': True, 'kernel__k1': 0.316**2 * RBF(length_scale=[0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]), 'kernel__k2': WhiteKernel(noise_level=0.1), 'kernel__k1__k1': 0.316**2, 'kernel__k1__k2': RBF(length_scale=[0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]), 'kernel__k1__k1__constant_value': 0.1, 'kernel__k1__k1__constant_value_bounds': (1e-23, 100000.0), 'kernel__k1__k2__length_scale': array([0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]), 'kernel__k1__k2__length_scale_bounds': (1e-23, 10000000000.0), 'kernel__k2__noise_level': 0.1, 'kernel__k2__noise_level_bounds': (1e-23, 100000.0), 'kernel': 0.316**2 * RBF(length_scale=[0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]) + WhiteKernel(noise_level=0.1), 'n_restarts_optimizer': 2, 'normalize_y': False, 'optimizer': 'fmin_l_bfgs_b', 'random_state': None}
Training
3.9108407497406006
1.0
learned kernel params
{'k1': 20.3**2 * RBF(length_scale=[0.00289, 9.29e-15, 8.81e-20, 0.00165, 2.7e+08, 3.2e+06, 0.233, 5.62e+07, 8.78e+07, 0.0169, 4.88e-21, 3.23e-20]), 'k2': WhiteKernel(noise_level=2.17e-13), 'k1__k1': 20.3**2, 'k1__k2': RBF(length_scale=[0.00289, 9.29e-15, 8.81e-20, 0.00165, 2.7e+08, 3.2e+06, 0.233, 5.62e+07, 8.78e+07, 0.0169, 4.88e-21, 3.23e-20]), 'k1__k1__constant_value': 411.28699807005, 'k1__k1__constant_value_bounds': (1e-23, 100000.0), 'k1__k2__length_scale': array([2.88935323e-03, 9.29401433e-15, 8.81112330e-20, 1.64832813e-03,
       2.70454686e+08, 3.20194179e+06, 2.32646715e-01, 5.62487948e+07,
       8.77636837e+07, 1.68642019e-02, 4.88384874e-21, 3.22536538e-20]), 'k1__k2__length_scale_bounds': (1e-23, 10000000000.0), 'k2__noise_level': 2.171274720012903e-13, 'k2__noise_level_bounds': (1e-23, 100000.0)}
```

Could you please edit your question such that your observation can be reproduced?

Comment: Thank you for your effort, I will update my sklearn version, and see if I can post my data

Comment: I've added the relevant example files, perhaps you can give it a second look. Any help would be really appreciated @adrin

Comment: but also in your results, the parameters are still unchanged. Odd.

Comment: @Ben, you mean the `length_scale`? That's a hyperparameter set by the user (or default value), not a parameter to be trained from the data (AFAIK) (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/gaussian_process/plot_gpr_co2.html)

Comment: the anisotropic RBF's length_scales are learned. It defines to which extent nearby samples are taken into account. Check your example, there they also change..

Comment: tnx, although your comment on ``n_restarts_optimizer`` is not correct. It also optimizes when n = 0, but than it uses the initial kernel parameters as initial guess for the maximum likelihood estimation, whereas it samples random values for the initial guess in the remaining restarts..

Comment: optimizing given a kernel is different than finding a kernel [hyperparameters] which result in the best optimization values. The two optimizations you're talking about happen on different levels.

Comment: I don't think so, let's agree we disagree :)